# SSH host key changed just after setting root password

Tags: ssh, security, putty, ssh-keys

This might sound super suspicious, but it just happened to me:

I run a rented Raspberry Pi as my own mail server and today I set a root password to eventually login as root directly. I did not yet check whether the default configuration forbids root login. I exited the SSH session and restartet Putty to login as root.

The access was denied and after restarting Putty again to login to the account which I usually use, the host seems to have changed its key and Putty warned me about this.

Between setting the root password and getting the warning from Putty about the changed host key, less than two minutes passed. Also, I mostly trust the client machine, it is a quite freshly set up Windows 10 machine I got from my employer for work.

Should I be concerned, that someone cracked my server in such a short time (I couldn't do it nearly that fast)? It would not make any sense to change the key after already having root access.

What would be the best to do now? Should I contanct the data center operator to physically shut down my machine? Or should I just connect via SSH anyway?

Comment: moved here from stackoverflow

Comment: Actually, if you have the default rpi login, and enable root login, it might actually get hacked instantly if the provider is specialized to rpi hosting.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that all users have very strong passwords so far, because default login credentials are definitely a big threat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ridiculous, but restarting the Windows client machine solved(!) the problem. The server's *auth.log* does not show any strange activities.

Comment: moved here from stackoverflow